# How I create a dropdown for radar chartjs from mysql database?

Tags: mysql, chart.js, dropdown

I have a mysql database named players and with these columns id, name, attack, defence, speed, dribbling and shoot.

I create a radar chart to show players data.

My code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

     <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">

let json = <?php include("datas.php");?>;
let label = [];
let data = [];

// generate label and data dynamically
json.forEach(e => {
    label.push(e.name);
    data.push([+e.attack, +e.defence, +e.speed, +e.shoot, +e.dribbling]);
});

let ctx = document.querySelector('#canvas').getContext('2d');
let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: ['attack', 'defence', 'speed','shoot','dribbling'],
        datasets: [{
            label: label[0],
            data: data[0],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,119,204,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(0,119,204, 0.5)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }, {
            label: label[1],
            data: data[1],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0 ,0.15)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0 ,0.45)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }, {
            label: label[2],
            data: data[2],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,119,204,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0 ,0.45)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            position: "top",
            text: "Radar test",
            fontSize: 14,
            fontColor: "#111"
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "bottom"
        },
        scale: {
            pointLabels: {
                fontSize: 11
            }
        }
    }
});
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Datas.php:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","players");
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM players_attributes ORDER BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

My question is how to create a radar chart with a dropdown filter by name?
The dropdown should show the list of players and the radar chart change for selected player.

[image: radar chart]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: Datas.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","players");
$sqlQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM players_attributes ORDER BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery);
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<option data-id='".$row['id']."' value='" . $row['name'] ."'>";
}
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$row));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question is another: how connect a dropdown with a radar chart?